# How do i install gnome on Debian and remote to it?

Tags: debian, graphical-user-interface

I have a debian server that's been up and running for a while now, I access it via putty and it works great, however i would like to add a gui to make things prettier to look at and easier for me to manage my server (what can i say - i grew up with windows...).  Can I do this solely from putty access?  I will need to install VNC or something similar to remote into it as it is sitting in a closet.  I would like to do this without having to take machine down, move into another room, hook up a monitor, etc.  Can I do this all from command line?  if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'm going to describe is using the GDM autologin which **can be unsecure if** someone has physical access to the machine.

First install **Gnome, gdm, vino** and **xorg**:

```
apt-get install gnome gdm xorg vino
```

Then activate autologin in gdm, edit **/etc/gdm/custom.conf** and add:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=yourusername
```

**Reboot.**

Then ssh as *yourusername* into the machine, and type this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /desktop/gnome/remote_access/authentication_methods '[vnc]'
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/prompt_enabled false
vino-passwd
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
```

**Reboot.**

Then try connecting to your machine using VNC.

Comment: I see a /etc/gdm/gdm.conf - is this the correct file?  or sould i create a new file called custom.conf?

Comment: yeah Try creating custom.conf, as this file will not overwritten when you update packages. If that does not work, try gdm.conf